# Respond to a change in checkbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I'm familiar with `.change()` however, this particular checkbox can be checked from the following

A: `this` checkbox

B: Select all checkbox in `<thead>`

C: Select parent `<tr>`

```
$('#tblSubmissions').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
    //only works with option A
});
```

is there a way to respond to a change in the value of the checkbox without needing something like knockout?

Comment: You've got to manually call the `change()` event each time you want your change handler to execute.

Comment: rather than `.attr({ 'checked': true })` ?

Comment: Yeah.. the handler doesn't actively watch any of the properties.

Comment: please can u explain in detail... here is my work...http://jsfiddle.net/pavanastechie/xz8z426f/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$('#tblSubmissions').change(function(){
if(this.checked) {
//dosomething 
}
});
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid watching any change on the entire table, thanks for the attempt

Comment: $('table').change(function(){
if(this.checked) {
//dosomething 
}
}); have you tried this